# Possible solution to ELB lacking A record support?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, haproxy, amazon-elb

Hey guys I was wondering if this seems like a viable solution to the age old problem of Amazon Elastic Load Balancer's lacking a dedicated IP, and thus A record support.

What if I created a micro/small instance and hooked it to an elastic IP. I can then use that IP as my A record address for my website. That instance will forward 100% of its traffic to an ELB load balancer address (Haproxy?), which will then operate normally and forward that traffic to my server pool.

With this architecture I can use my A-record and an ELB.

- Are there any downsides to this aside from the cost of the initial instance that forwards its traffic to the ELB?
- Will this double forwarding create too much lag or is it really negligible since they're all in AWS?

Thanks for feedback.

Comment: I'm thinking of using this same method. Were you able to get it implemented and if so, how well does it work?

Answer (score 2):

If you are currently using Route53 for you DNS, it does have support for handling zone apex.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=260459

Not sure if this answers your question since you didn't mention why you need a dedicated ip.

Comment: I don't need a dedicated IP per se, I just needed a way to route traffic to my domain with an A record. I did not want to use the www.website.com method using a cname to route to the ELB. I'll look into your link, as I'm currently not sure what zone apex is. Thanks!

Comment: If you are hosting DNS with Route53, you can point `http://mydomain.com` (no subdomain required) at an ELB using a special type of A record for only available on AWS.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any downsides to this aside from the cost of the initial instance that forwards its traffic to the ELB?

Er, yes. You're loosing about 99.9% of the benefits of ELB.

> Will this double forwarding create too much lag or is it really negligible since they're all in AWS?

No, the lag should be small (sub-milisecond).  The two main problems are:

1) Your instance will become a *bottleneck* when your traffic increases. You won't be able to survive a sudden rush, such as being linked from a high-traffic website like Slashdot or Oprah.

The whole point of ELB is that they can manage scaling (the frontend and the backend) for you. If you insert a single box in the flow, it kinda prevents ELB from doing anything useful.

Also, the micro instance can take *very little* traffic. You have to go to at least a m1.large if you won't want your network packets throttled.

2) Your instance will become a *Single Point Of Failure*. When your box dies, your website will be down. ELB can prevent problems on both the front and backend with redundancy.

Perhaps if you explained why you needed an A record?

(It is also possible to run your own front-end(s): Just create a box with an EIP, and put nginx and/or HAProxy on it. But as with everything, there are trade-offs.)